# Moving Database From SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

We want to move Database From SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016. I'm looking help on the following -

> 1. Is there any way to know my database is fully compatible with SQL Server 2016 or not before actual moving it?
> 2. Is there any way to know all depreciated features on SQL server 2016 which has been used in the my database (SQL Server 2012)?

Please Suggest any Free tools which can help to know this before moving to SQL Server 2016.

Comment: The answer to all is "the docs themselves". SQL Server docs are great. Have you read the docs on migration and upgrading?

Comment: As for support, you're running on a version unsupported for some years. SQL Server 2016 is the *oldest* version in mainstream support so you should probably consider upgrading to 2017. Fixes are rolled into the newer versions, which btw get them earlier than older ones. If you care about stability, you shouldn't be using the oldest available version

Comment: As the docs explain, you can restore a database to a newer server and use it in a compatibility mode to see if your *applications and queries* have any issues. This isn't a matter of deprecated features but queries resulting in different execution plans.  All versions introduce changes to the query optimizer, cardinality estimators etc. In fact, even service packs can introduce changes.  Once you're confident you can change the compatibility level.

Answer (score -1):

Detach your sql 2012 DB and Attach it to your sql server 2016

Note that you cannot attach 2016 DB to 2012 after attaching it to 2016 you need to take backup for safety

Comment: That does not answer either of the OP's questions.